# Strange behavior in Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise Edition

Tags: visual-studio

I have a weird behavior in Visual Studio that just popped up a couple of days ago. I might of course been mistakenly hit some keyboard combo, but not sure so here we go.

If I have a c# project open and write anything that the Intellisense recognize, I have to hit space (or dot) for example TWICE.

So, instead of typing

```
int i = 0;
```

I have to hit space twice between int and i.

Same thing if I try the :

```
person.FirstName = "Bob";
```

Then I have to type the dot between person and FirstName.

Another case:

```
SomeClass s = new SomeClass();
```

Not I need to type SomeClass s = new
and then two spacebar strokes to get it to display the SomeClass(); which I can just hit tab to get.

If I work on some web project and edit a .cshtml file the intellisense tries to auto complete when I type normal tex. So for instance:
`<p>So rob</p>`

Will it then "auto complete" as:

```
<p>scommando rubyob</p>
```

If I don't watch out.

Anyone else had this issue?
I tried reinstalling the IntelliCode from the VS Installer, but to no avail.

Comment: I have no constructive input, but just wanted to say that I am also experiencing this issue.